# Getting "The prop A is marked as required in B, but its value is 'undefined'." even when it's not set as required

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

So I used to have some props set as required. Then I changed my code, got the above mentioned error. Went to the component and removed the `.isRequired` and added default props... and I'm still getting the error???

My project is still kinda small, so I'm pretty sure I haven't duplicated the component in some weird way. Thought it could be some strange caching mechanism but the problem persists even when I run in incognito mode. I also restarted the application in case prop types somehow persisted after WebPack recompiles the project.

The error:

`Warning: Failed prop type: The prop 'artist.isRequired' is marked as required in 'ArtistCard', but its value is 'undefined'.`

and

`Warning: Failed prop type: The prop 'trackMap.isRequired' is marked as required in 'ArtistCard', but its value is 'undefined'.`

How my prop types look in ArtistCard:

```
ArtistCard.defaultProps = {
  artist: {},
  trackMap: {},
};

ArtistCard.propTypes = {
  artist: PropTypes.shape(PropTypes.object),
  trackMap: PropTypes.shape(PropTypes.object),
};
```

Double checked that I saved all relevant files as well. What could possible reasons for this behaviour be? Where could I try to debug it?

Comment: How about using this: ArtistCard.propTypes = { artist: PropTypes.object, trackMap:PropTypes.object };

Comment: Are the props being overridden by your state management/redux maybe to null?

Comment: I would also do a full text search in your project for `ArtistCard`. I've had it happen that I clone a file and rename it but forget to redefine the name of the default class I'm exporting. This will cause the error message to say `ArtistCard` even if it's a component you never intended to call ArtistCard

Comment: @Hamed That actually works (why tho!?). The reason they looked the way they did was because of the es-lint error react/forbid-prop-types. I admit my "solution" to that error was kinda lazy and perhaps I should define an actual artist-objectshape? Or will this break the ".isRequired" conundrum as well?

Comment: @MrJalapeno That rule is off by default. Is there any reason you used that? It wont break the isRequired. ArtistCard.propTypes = { artist: PropTypes.object.isRequired, trackMap:PropTypes.object.isRequired } should work fine as well.

Comment: @Hamed I probably have it because I extend `["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended", "airbnb"]` thinking about removing it but it still feels like a reasonable lint to have. I'm still kinda confused as to why writing `PropTypes.shape(PropTypes.object)` magically makes the prop required? :(

Comment: @MrJalapeno I am also using react/recommended plugin but not the airbnb one. This post may also answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45764828/9598077

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `PropTypes.object` instead of `PropTypes.shape(PropTypes.object)`

Comment: That actually works (why tho!?). The reason they looked the way they did was because of the es-lint error `react/forbid-prop-types`. I admit my "solution" to that error was kinda lazy and perhaps I should define an actual artist-objectshape? Or will this break the ".isRequired" conundrum as well?

Comment: You can define the shape and use `isRequired` that is no problem. 
Example: `ArtistCard.propTypes = {
  artist: PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }).isRequired,
  trackMap: PropTypes.object
};`

you can define it or use only `PropTypes.object.isRequired` it depends what do you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the linting errors I changed the propTypes to this instead:

```
ArtistCard.propTypes = {
  artist: PropTypes.shape({}),
  trackMap: PropTypes.shape({}),
};
```