# type specification of prop `systemConfig` is invalid; the type checker function must return `null` or an `Error` but returned a function

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-proptypes

I am doing proptype check in my React.js code like this

```
const { a, b ,c } = this.props
```

where `a, b, c` are my objects or response coming from API

and in my propTypes check my code look's like

```
ComponentName.propTypes = {
a: PropTypes.objectOf,
b: PropTypes.objectOf,
c: PropTypes.objectOf,
};
```

in Default PropTypes assigning it like this

```
ComponentName.defaultProps = {
a: {
key1: '',
key2: '',
},
b: {
key3: '',
key4: '',
},
},
```

But when i am compiling my code it is giving me this error

> type specification of prop `a` is invalid; the type checker function must return `null` or an `Error` but returned a function. You may have forgotten to pass an argument to the type checker creator (arrayOf, instanceOf, objectOf, oneOf, oneOfType, and shape all require an argument)

Please can someone help in removing this warning from the console what can be the workaround

Comment: change to `a: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string), b: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string), ... `

Comment: have done that it gives a warning of 

Invalid prop `a.key` of type `number` supplied to `ComponentName`, expected `string`

Comment: if you are passing `number` as props then use `a: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.number), ...`

Comment: actually that particular object have multiple data types as its key value pair's so my question is can i pass multiple PropTypes.dataType as objectOf parameter

Answer (score 5):

Use `PropTypes.any` for value of any data type

```
ComponentName.propTypes = {
 a: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any),
 b: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any),
 c: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any),
};
```

Comment: A bit confused on `objectOf` vs. `shape`. Going to look into it now.

Comment: Well...that was EZ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45764746/react-proptypes-objectof-vs-shape