# React PropTypes checks for the wrong type

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a problem with a PropTypes definition in React, i defined the type of the *'doc_count_error_upper_bound'* field to be of type ***'number'***, but **it gets checked against type *'object'***.
I presume somewhere the PropTypes definition breaks down for some reason, since both the data and the definition seem to be correct, and the other fields are treated ok.

The app is composed of a series of components organized with react-grid-layout https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout

propTypes warning:

```
 index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `data[0].subAggregationTerm.doc_count_error_upper_bound` of type `number` supplied to `MultiBarChart`, expected `object`.
        in MultiBarChart (at App.jsx:219)
        in div (at App.jsx:179)
        in div (at App.jsx:178)
        in Resizable (created by GridItem)
        in DraggableCore (created by GridItem)
        in GridItem (created by ReactGridLayout)
        in div (created by ReactGridLayout)
        in ReactGridLayout (created by ResponsiveReactGridLayout)
        in ResponsiveReactGridLayout (created by WidthProvider)
        in WidthProvider (at App.jsx:231)
        in div (at App.jsx:229)
        in App (at src/index.js:6)
```

Component propTypes definition

```
MultiBarChart.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      key_as_string: PropTypes.string,
      key: PropTypes.number,
      doc_count: PropTypes.number,
      subAggregationTerm: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.shape({
        doc_count_error_upper_bound: PropTypes.number,
        sum_other_doc_count: PropTypes.number,
        buckets: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
          key: PropTypes.number,
          doc_count: PropTypes.number,
        })),
      })),
    }),
  ).isRequired,
  onHit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

Data:

```
const dateHistogramSubAggs2 = [{
  key_as_string: '1576105200',
  key: 1576105200000,
  doc_count: 0,
  subAggregationTerm: {
    doc_count_error_upper_bound: 0,
    sum_other_doc_count: 0,
    buckets: [{
      key: 'label_1',
      doc_count: 215,
     }],
   },
 }];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could fix your problem removing `PropTypes.objectOf` and leaving only `PropTypes.shape` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45764746/react-proptypes-objectof-vs-shape) you could see why):

```
MultiBarChart.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      key_as_string: PropTypes.string,
      key: PropTypes.number,
      doc_count: PropTypes.number,
      subAggregationTerm: PropTypes.shape({
        doc_count_error_upper_bound: PropTypes.number,
        sum_other_doc_count: PropTypes.number,
        buckets: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
          key: PropTypes.number,
          doc_count: PropTypes.number
        }))
      }),
    }),
  ).isRequired,
  onHit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```