# PropTypes: initial useState returns object and fails propTypes check when adding first item

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, typechecking, react-proptypes

I am not sure in how far this is intended behavior and how much of it is user error;

I initialize a `dictionary` state as an empty array.

```
const [dictionary, setDictionary] = useState([]);
```

Console logging `dictionary` returns to me an empty array `[]`, while `typeof dictionary` returns to me an object (why?).

```
 > []
     length: 0
     __proto__: Array(0)

 > object
```

The array is eventually propagated by user input in the shape of

```
[
  {
    word: 'test',
    definition: 'test'
  }
]
```

I use React's `propTypes` and check the integrity like this:

```
Core.propTypes = {
  dictionary: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.objectOf(
      PropTypes.shape({
        definition: PropTypes.string,
        word: PropTypes.string.isRequired
      })
    )
  )
};
```

On initial render I get no error, but when adding the first item to the array, the console tells me:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `dictionary[0].word` of type `string` supplied 
to `Core`, expected `object`.
```

When changing the PropType check to

```
WordRandom.propTypes = {
  dictionary: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.objectOf(
      PropTypes.string.isRequired
    )
  )
};
```

adding the first item does not cause the warning. Am I not supposed to/allowed to check each item in the object?

No subsequent addition to the array triggers the error, so I'm wondering if I goofed something up or if it's intended behavior that doesn't matter?

EDIT: for clarification:

```
setDictionary([...dictionary, { word, definition }]);
```

where word and definition are strings

Comment: Please provide your `setDictionary` code. Also `typeof dictionary === 'object'` cause Arrays are object. If you want to know if it's an array then use `Array.isArray(dictionary)`

Comment: @JCQuintas added the `setDictionary` function at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Just use shape

Shape is already an object. You're adding extra levels that you don't need in your type.

```
Core.propTypes = {
  dictionary: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      definition: PropTypes.string,
      word: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    })
  )
};
```

Comment: Would you then say that shape({definition: ..., word: ...}) and objectOf(PropTypes.string) are the same since I expect both values to always be strings??

Comment: @Hendrik in a way, yes. It will expect every prop to be strings. Though, if you give it `{ someProp: '' }` it will be accepted as well. If you know the `shape` of the object beforehand then it's better to use `shape`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you want to remove `proptypes.objectOf`. The `objectOf(shape())` will expect an object of objects.

```js
PropTypes.arrayOf(
  PropTypes.shape({
    definition: PropTypes.string,
    word: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  })
)
```

Refer to this question for more info: [React propTypes: objectOf vs shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45764746/react-proptypes-objectof-vs-shape)